# How to change alpha for background image (camera) with python?

Tags: python, camera, image

I'm trying to figure out how to change the Alpha (image opacity) for a background image in the Camera settings "Background Images", but can't quite figure it out, any ideas?

The tooltip says `CameraBackgroundImage.alpha` and `bpy.data.cameras['Camera name'] ... alpha`

[image]

**Q:** How to change alpha for background image (camera) with python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Python console**

Given the tooltip, and the property being in 'DATA' panel can see that the property belongs to the data part of the camera.

I find autocomplete in the console handy for working these things out.

The data part of the scene camera (it's also the active object `C.object`.  In console C is a shortcut for `bpy.context` (see startup message).

```
>>> C.scene.camera
bpy.data.objects['Camera']

>>> cam = C.scene.camera.data
>>> cam
bpy.data.cameras['Camera']
```

Ok, if you autocomplete on `cam.<TAB>` will notice that it has a `background_images` property...  Ok it's a collection

Here I've looped over the collection and displayed the alpha and its attached image.

```
>>> for img in cam.background_images:
...     img.alpha, img.image
...     
(0.5, bpy.data.images['1b.jpg'])
```

Set first in list to alpha 1

```
>>> cam.background_images[0].alpha = 1
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you for the clear answer, it works very well. How do I iterate over all and set them all to alpha 1? 

I can set them by    

cam.data.background_images[0].alpha = 1
cam.data.background_images[1].alpha = 1
cam.data.background_images[2].alpha = 1
cam.data.background_images[3].alpha = 1

But I'm sure there is a more efficient way of doing it. 

I tried a few different things, but they didn't work. This is one of the things I tried, but bi has no attribute of alpha.

```
bi = cam.data.background_images
for x in bi:
    bi.alpha = 1
```